# How can I add action buttons/actions to UILocalNotification alert?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have a local notification scheduled in my app, and right now I get a generic cancel (cross) button as I swipe the alert to the left.

I'm curious if I can add custom buttons/actions to it like on the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I prepared for you some snipped code which shows notification with one button 10 second after `ViewDidLoad` method did shown.

```
  import UIKit

    class TestViewController: UIViewController {

        let category = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let restartAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            restartAction.identifier = "xx"
            restartAction.destructive = false
            restartAction.title = "Restart"
            restartAction.activationMode = .Background
            restartAction.authenticationRequired = false

            let categoryIdentifier = "category.identifier"
            category.identifier = categoryIdentifier
            category.setActions([restartAction], forContext: .Minimal)
            category.setActions([restartAction], forContext: .Default)

            let categories = Set(arrayLiteral: category)
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound], categories: categories)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)


            let localNotif = UILocalNotification()
            localNotif.alertBody = "testBody"
            localNotif.category = categoryIdentifier

            // Notification will be shown after 10 second (IMPORTANT: if you want to see notification you have to close or put app into background)
            localNotif.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(10)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotif)
        }

    }
```

Note: you have to handle action in AppDelegate method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?,
                forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

  completionHandler()
}
```

Of course my code is not as clean as it should be, but you have to know that I wrote it only for presentation purposes.

This code is written in Swift but convertion to Objective C should be very simple.