# How to Schedule unclearable or non-removable Local Notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilocalnotification

I want add simple local notification which unclearable for particular time. like 10 minutes you can not clear it. if solution is possible through other way suggestion appreciated.
Anyone having idea about it?

Comment: @Bilal I think u don't read full question. I asked about unclearable.

Comment: Sorry, I miss understood it..  I have removed the flag.

Comment: What is 'unclearable'?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is when you are dismissing all pending notification reset the particular notification again or you can remove other notifications by their identifier and keep the particular notification

here is the code to fetch all pending notifications.

```
   let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in

        print(requests)

        for request in requests {


            srrNotification.append(request)
            print(request)
        }
    })
```

Comment: when app is closed and I am clear notification. above code doesn't execute.

Comment: when app is closed how you are clearing notifications?

Comment: you can get action callback of clear from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144510/how-can-i-add-action-buttons-actions-to-uilocalnotification-alert.  try this

Comment: https://github.com/akash-sisodia/NotificationDemoSwift  I have also created a demo

Comment: I think you have to review question one more time. your code is also clear notification when swipe left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148321/discussion-between-rushi-and-akash-singh-sisodia).